# Oracle SQL reformat table

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a table like this:

```
COMPANY    ZONE    SITE    DATE    KWHTOTAL    KWHIT    KWHCLIMA
   1        0       11  01/01/2018  10000      5000      3000
   2        0       23  01/02/2018  7000       4000      1500
...
```

I need to transform the table into this

```
COMPANY    ZONE    SITE    DATE       KWH    TYPE
   1        0       11   01/01/2018  10000   KWHTOTAL
   1        0       11   01/01/2018  5000    KWHIT
   1        0       11   01/01/2018  3000    KWHCLIMA
   2        0       23   01/02/2018  7000    KWHTOTAL
   2        0       23   01/02/2018  4000    KWHIT
   2        0       23   01/02/2018  1500    KWHCLIMA
```

...

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `UNPIVOT`, which should be supported in Oracle `12c`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
UNPIVOT (KWH FOR kwh_field IN (KWHTOTAL AS 'KWHTOTAL', KWHIT AS 'KWHIT',
    KWHCLIMA AS 'KWHCLIMA'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!. I choose your method, it takes less time.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `union all`.  However, Oracle 12c supports lateral joins.  So you can do:

```
select t.COMPANY, t.ZONE, t.SITE, t.DATE, tt.KWH, tt.TYPE
from t cross apply
     (select 'KWHTOTAL' as type, KWHTOTAL as kwh from dual union all
      select 'KWHIT' as type, KWHIT as kwh from dual union all
      select 'KWHCLIMA' as type, KWHCLIMA as kwh from dual
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Thanks for yor help!